# pandas error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe.

[image]

```
distdf=pd.DataFrame(dist)
for i in range(len(distdf)):
    if distdf.loc[i]==distdf.loc[i+1]:
        print("true")
    else:
        print('no')
```

but I have a error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code failed because `distdf.loc[i] == distdf.loc[i+1]` attempts
to compare **whole rows**, i.e. two *Series* objects.

Some impovement would be if you wrote:
`if distdf.loc[i, 'DISTINGUISH']==distdf.loc[i+1, 'DISTINGUISH']:`,
i.e. compared *DISTINGUISH* elements in each row (current and the next).

But this code would also fail on the last turn of the loop, because
when you "stay" on the last row, there is no next row, so then
*KeyError* exception is raised.

There is a simpler, more *pandasonic* approach to get a list of your values,
without any loop.

Assume that your DataFrame (*distdf*) contains:

```
    DISTINGUISH
0             1
1             1
2             2
3             2
4             3
5             3
6            32
7            32
8            33
9            33
10           34
11           34
```

As you want to operate on its only column, to keep the code short,
let's save it under *col0*:

```
col0 = distdf.iloc[:, 0]
```

Then, to get your list of values, without any loop, run:

```
np.where(col0 == col0.shift(-1), 'true', 'no')
```

The result, for the above data, is:

```
array(['true', 'no', 'true', 'no', 'true', 'no', 'true', 'no', 'true',
       'no', 'true', 'no'], dtype='<U4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you only have one column, `distdf.loc[i]` is still a Pandas Series object and not just the integer contained in the only column, thus the error.

What you could do is comparing the value of each cell of the single column using `.values` to avoid getting this error :

```
# you also need to use len(distdf)-1 and not len(distdf)
for i in range(len(distdf)-1):
    if distdf.loc[i].values == distdf.loc[i+1].values:
        print("true")
    else:
        print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dist =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
distdf = pd.DataFrame(dist)
for i in range(len(distdf)-1):
    res = distdf.loc[i].values==distdf.loc[i].values
    if True in res:
        print("true")
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: Although your solution might solve the problem, please add an explanation as to why it works to make it more effective